# Execute 4 tasks simultaneously, auto-starting another as and when each completes

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a list of 100 urls. I need to fetch the html content of those urls. Lets say I don't use the async version of `DownloadString` and instead do the following.

```
var task1 = SyTask.Factory.StartNew(() => new WebClient().DownloadString("url1"));
```

**What I want to achieve is to get the html string for at max 4 urls at a time.**

I start 4 tasks for the first four urls. Assume the 2nd url completes, I want to immediately start the 5th task for the 5th url. And so on. This way at max 4 only 4 urls will be downloaded, and for all purposes there will always be 4 urls being downloaded, ie till all 100 are processed.

I can't seem to visualize how will I actually achieve this. There must be an established pattern for doing this. Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Following up on @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment to use `Parallel.ForEach`, I wrote the following

```
var urls = new List<string>();
var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var lockObj = new object();
Parallel.ForEach(urls,
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                 url =>
                 {
                     var str = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
                     lock (lockObj)
                     {
                         results[url] = str;
                     }
                 });
```

I think the above reads better than creating individual tasks and using a semaphore to limit concurrency. That said having never used or worked with `Parallel.ForEach`, I am unsure if this correctly does what I need to do.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of 4?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, could you review the code I have just added to the question. Is that close to how you would have solved it?

Comment: @AmithGeorge it sets an upper limit as 4, but doesn't guarantee it will run 4 tasks in parallel. It may be 2 in a 2-core machine, for ex.

Comment: If you are going to use Tasks, there's a WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync. But you are better off with an HttpClient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(4);
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    sem.Wait();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new WebClient().DownloadString(url))
         .ContinueWith(t => sem.Release());    
}
```

Comment: The simplicity of this is beautiful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `Task.WaitAny`is much better for what you're trying to achieve than `ContinueWith`

```
int tasksPerformedCount = 0

Task[] tasks = //initial 4 tasks

while(tasksPerformedCount< 100)
{
    //returns the index of the first task to complete, as soon as it completes
    int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks); 
    tasksPerformedCount++;

    //replace it with a new one
    tasks[index] = //new task            
}
```

**Edit**:
Another example of `Task.WaitAny` from http://www.amazon.co.uk/Exam-Ref-70-483-Programming-In/dp/0735676828/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1378105711&sr=8-1&keywords=exam+ref+70-483+programming+in+c

```
namespace Chapter1 {    
  public static class Program     {         
    public static void Main()         { 
      Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[3]; 
        tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return 1; });
        tasks[1] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return 2; });
        tasks[2] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return 3; });

        while (tasks.Length > 0)
        {
          int i = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
          Task<int> completedTask = tasks[i];

          Console.WriteLine(completedTask.Result);

          var temp = tasks.ToList();
          temp.RemoveAt(i);
          tasks = temp.ToArray();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Suppose two tasks are finished at the same time.

Comment: I don't know, I feel the code doesn't convey the intent clearly enough. On top of that, I am not entirely sure how it will behave under various circumstances.

Comment: Since WaitAny blocks the thread until one of the tasks finishes, then two loops will happen in a quick succession, creating two new threads almost immediately.

Comment: That's the exact intent of `Task.WaitAny`, according to the book `Exam Ref 70-483: Programming In C#`. I think it's pretty clear..

Comment: I'll post the example from the book

Comment: Oh and oops, i forgot to increment the counter! I just updated the answer.